# Installing gnuplot on Mavericks

Tags: gnuplot, homebrew, osx-mavericks

I am trying to reinstall gnuplot after the upgrade to Mavericks (since it kept throwing errors while trying to launch it).

I am doing this with homebrew, since the system told me to uninstall Macports/fink

```
brew install gnuplot
```

and it gets stuck during the "make"

I tried to follow some instructions found around the net like doing this before install:

```
sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/include/
sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/lib
```

but the result is always :

```
==> Installing dependencies for gnuplot: pkg-config, readline, libpng, jpeg, gd, lua
==> Installing gnuplot dependency: pkg-config
==> Downloading http://pkgconfig.freedesktop.org/releases/pkg-config-0.28.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/pkg-config-0.28.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.28 --disable-host-tool --with-internal-glib --with-pc-path=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig
==> make
```

Any advice?

Comment: Run `brew doctor` and do as the doctor says!

Answer (score 2):

Try running `brew install -v` to get the build output.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue today, it hangs because the LaTeX terminal requires the (obsolete) subfigure package. The easiest fix is to install this LaTeX package in your `texmf` directory. For MacTeX this is `~/Library/texmf`. Afterwards you can install gnuplot with brew.

In steps:

- Download: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/subfigure
- Put the contents in `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex` (remember `~/Library` is hidden, and the `texmf` directory must be created if it doesn't exist)
- Run `latex subfigure.ins` in that folder
- Run `brew install gnuplot`

Answer (score 0):

I found it quite tedious to install `gnuplot` and make it talk to `latex` on Mac OS X. If you don't mind an older version of `gnuplot`, you can find an installer inside an `extra` subdirectory of the `gnu-octave` program at `sourceforge`. But this convenient installer is no longer packaged with `gnu-octave`. If you want the latest version of `gnuplot`, I have detailed the steps I followed to make it work here (my answer is the one that expands on **Alan Munn**'s great answer):

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71160/how-to-use-gnu-plot-to-plot-diagrams-in-texshop?lq=1